# Flash Full screen App wth video inside

Tags: video, fullscreen, flash-cs6

I'd like to add a video in a flash application (developped with flash professionnal CS6). Everything is looking good, i have my video in the top right corner because i use the rest of the application for other purpose.

When i enter full screen, the video is also in full screen, hiding all my app! I'd like to be in full screen (my app in full screen), but with the video in a box in top right corner.

Is that possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Found it,

I used : flvplay.fullScreenTakeOver = false;

That's what i needed :)